# Given a path, find the zypper package and the repository

Tags: linux, package, suse, zypper

I'm using SUSE12SP5 system. Given a path, I'm trying to get it's package. So for example, for `etc/ssh/ssh_config` I want to get `openssh`. For that I use the following command:

```
> rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]" /etc/ssh/ssh_config
openssh
```

So basically I get a list of paths and run this command on it to find the packages (if there are any). Also, I read in another topic that I can use `zypper info packagename` to find the repository. It works for `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` but I noticed that there some packages that I can't find which repository the package was installed from. So for example for `/tmp` the `rpm` command results with:

```
> rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]" /tmp
filesystemcfengine
```

But if I run `zypper info` on the packages I get:

```
> zypper info filesystemcfengine
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...


package 'filesystemcfengine' not found.
```

So to sum up, I want to do the following: Given a list of paths, I want to find it's package (if there is any) and the repository from which is was installed. How it can be done?

Comment: what does `rpm -qi filesystemcfengine` give you?

Comment: @ChrisMaes I get `package filesystemcfengine is not installed`

Comment: well, I think /tmp is way to wide for detecting "what path did this app write to", consider exclude that first ?

Answer (score 0):

CFEngine is a configuration management tool, which modifies the filesystem to achieve a configuration goal.

If the files you are inspecting were provisioned by cfengine, it might explain why you get "filesystemcfengine" from your rpm query.

Comment: But the question is how do I find all the dependencies?